# pass an object creat in the main of a class to another class

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Example
{
    public void static main(String[] args)
    {
        Object obj = new Object();
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass(obj);
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    private Object object;
    public OtherClass(Object ob)
    {
    this.object = ob;
    }
}
```

Now I would use OtherClass in another main. how can i do?
this is the class where I want to use OtherClass object created in the class Example before

```
public class myownmain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Here I need OtherClass object created in Example class
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you are running 2 applications, and you want to pass data between them? Take a look at [`Inter-process communication`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad yes exactly. it is what I trying to do...But I failed

Answer (score 1):

The main functions in those different classes represent different applications and you won't be able to refer to objects created in one application from another.

In case you want to use similar objects in the other main function you simply have to create new instances and use those instead. It is not obvious though what you are trying achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A Java program usually has only one `main` method, or to be more specific, only one `main` method will be called when your program starts. However, it is possible to call the other `main` method from yours.

You cannot do this without restructuring the `Example` class above, because the `OtherClass` instance is a local variable in the `main` method, thus you cannot retrieve it.

One solution would be to instantiate the `OtherClass` in your own `main` method:

```
public class myownmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass(obj);
    }
}
```

The other option is to rewrite the `Example` class to expose the `OtherClass` instance as a static attribute:

```
public class Example {
    private static OtherClass oc;

    public static OtherClass getOc() {
        return oc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        oc = new OtherClass(obj);
    }
}
```

Then you can get this instance after calling `Example.main`:

```
public class myownmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example.main(args);
        OtherClass oc = Example.getOc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one `main(String[] args)` method. If you want to pass *OtherClass* from  *Example class* create method like

```
public static OtherClass getOtherClass(Object obj) {
   return new OtherClass(obj);
}
```

and then in *MyOwnMain class* just add

```
Object obj = new Object();
OtherClass oc = Example.getOtherClass(obj);
```

But as meant *@Eng.Fouad* if you want to have two running apps, just follow his link.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution it is not comfortable for my case study because the Object obj should be an istance of a web server.I can't pass an instance of a web server twice

Comment: because Object obj = new Object() in my case is an istance of a web server.It is already create in exxaple class.I can't pass it again to myownmain because in that way it should be created twice